# How to print contents of dst_entry in Linux Kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I would like to know how I can print the contents within `dst_entry` structure which was set using `skb_dst_set` function and retrieved using `skb_dst(dst)` in Linux Kernel 2.6.35.

Can anyone please let me know.

Comment: Incidentally, printk is one way.

Comment: The definition of what is inside the struct is at: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/net/dst.h#L32

Answer (score 1):

Like all other kernel datastructures, struct dst_entry is also combined of many other internal structures. So If you are particular about what you want to print, I can help you. You can find the definition of struct dst_entry in include/net/dst.h. Reading the definition will help you.